# Правда ли, что слова притча и приток — однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Книга Екклесиаста 12:9 "и ухо иследит красоты приточныя"

Answer (score 1):

Нет, эти слова содержат разные корни:

*приток* происходит от глаг. *течь*,

а *притча* — от глаг. *тыкать*.

Насчет последнего хорошо написано в этимологическом онлайн-словаре  Н. М. Шанского:

> **При́тча.** Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -j-) от притъка «нежданный случай, происшествие» (в диалектах еще известно),
>   производного от притъкнѫтисѧ «случиться, произойти» (к развитию
>   значения см. случай, приключение и пр.). Притча буквально — «особенный
>   случай», затем — «рассказ о нем». См. *тыкать*.